# Solr Configuration - Connection Failed! Test Again?

Tags: magento, solr

I'm trying to get Apache Solr configured with Magento EE and am not having any luck. I have a freshly installed Solr server ready and can access the Solr dashboard. As far as I understand from the Magento docs all I need to do is tell Magento how to connect to the Solr server in the System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search section.

In this admin screen I give it all the details it needs and then press the Test Connection button but all it does is change the button text to read "Connection Failed! Test Again?"

I don't know where to go from here. I don't see anything in the Magento system or exception logs so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you see the request in the Solr Log at all? Have you configured Solr Logging? Do you get a different error message with a non-existant path? Do you see the request if you give it the path to a different service that you have a working log for? What is the path you give to Magento?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solr so all I know is I can access the dashboard. I can see it in the logs when I access the dashboard but I do not see anything when trying to connect from Magento. I'm using the path "solr" in the Magento configuration. The Connection Failed message is the same even if I give it a made-up hostname.

Comment: My first thought would be that you at least have to give it a complete set of values that point to your [solr server in the configuration](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee/user_guide/Magento_Enterprise_Edition_User_Guide.html#search_seo/search-configuration-solr.html). The path should be without any anchor part - usually just solr/corename.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I wasn't copying the Solr configuration files from Magento over to the Solr server.

For example, in my case I had to copy lib/Apache/solr/conf from my Magento EE root  to /etc/solr/example/solr/conf on the Solr server.